# android listview layout error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am working on one application in which Activity consists of asynchronous tasks to get List1 and List2 from the server... but when I opened that application List2 loads below List1 and List2 is displaying first when application opened, so I have to scroll up to get List1... How to solve this problem? thanks in advance

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">  

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

          <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1550dp"
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            />            

            <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1550dp"
            android:id="@+id/list2"
            />           

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

java file

```
public class Mysubscription extends AppCompatActivity {

    static Mysubscription INSTANCE;
    public static String name2 = "name";
    public static String books2 = "books";
    public static String registration_fee = "registration_fee";

    private Toolbar topToolBar1;
    LinearLayout a;
    String Subsribed;
    Button Renew;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray12;
    private Toolbar topToolBar;
    ListView listview3;
    mysub1 adapter;
    mysub2 adapter2;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    private JSONArray gg;
    private JSONObject obj;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.subscribe1);
        INSTANCE=this;            

        new DownloadJSON1().execute();
        new DownloadJSON2().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask

    public class DownloadJSON1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        API o9=new API();        

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address

            Servicehandler json = new Servicehandler();
            jsonarray12  = json.getJSONFromUrl(o9.subscription1);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray12.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray12.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("books", jsonobject.getString("books"));
                    map.put("registration_fee", jsonobject.getString("registration_fee"));

                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new mysub1(Mysubscription.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview3.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
        }
    }

    public class DownloadJSON2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        API o9=new API();
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address

            Servicehandler json = new Servicehandler();
            jsonarray12  = json.getJSONFromUrl(o9.subscription1);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray12.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray12.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("books", jsonobject.getString("books"));
                    map.put("registration_fee", jsonobject.getString("registration_fee"));

                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter2 = new mysub2(Mysubscription.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview3.setAdapter(adapter2);
            // Close the progressdialog
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: share also your source code, the part regarding how do you populate those lists

Comment: source code added...

Comment: declare different ListView variables in activity class and initialize them in oncreate method

Comment: maybe the download2 is simply faster than the first, can you try to call new `DownloadJSON2().execute();` in the `onPostExecute` of the first download class?

Answer (score 0):

Make a callback that tracks, when both lists are loaded.

When that is done, you just call `scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);` or `scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0)`, depending on what works for you.

Of course give your Scrollview an ID and get it into your `scrollView` variable before calling it with `scrollView = (ScrollView)getViewById(R.id.myScrollView);`

Answer (score 0):

change your layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" /></LinearLayout>
```

listview are by default scrollable so no need to declare in ScrollView. I hope this will help you. All the best